# Changing an elements ID using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to change the id 'character' to 'characterSelected'

```
var character = document.getElementById('character');
var characterSelected = document.getElementById('characterSelected');

function klik() {
    character.innerHTML = characterSelected;
}

character.addEventListener('click', klik);
```

This is what I have so far but it doensn't seem to work. I want to do this using Javascript only, no jQuery.

Thanks

Comment: You should learn a bit about how the DOM works. Once you do, this stuff makes much more sense, and you won't be guessing at solutions.

Comment: As to your problem, you seem to have an idea in mind but are showing an attempt at a solution instead of fully describing the problem. What are you ultimately trying to achieve that makes you think you need to change the ID of an element?

Comment: I want to change the css of an image when its clicked.

Comment: First, please heed the advice given in the answer below. As to your problem, if you have an element with the ID `character`, and you want to change its CSS properties when clicked, change the code in the `klik` function to something like `this.style.color = "red";` or whatever. Or you can add a CSS class to updates its styles, which is usually cleaner. `this.classList.add("someClassName")`

Answer (score 1):

You tried something, it didn't work. Now is the time to look up the standard properties and functions you're using incorrectly. If guessing doesn't work, always look for reliable documentation.

A good reference would be the Mozilla Developer Network (MDN). It's a wiki-style encyclopedia about the web, its standards and current browser compatibility. If you look at the page about [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML), you'll find the following:

> The Element.innerHTML property sets or gets the HTML syntax describing
>   the element's descendants.

This means that the innerHTML property is used to replace the content of a tag as if you wrote that HTML inside it. Not what you want.

What you wanted was to change the id of an element. If you search for element id, you'll land on the [Element.id](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id) page. And how practical, there's an example:

> ```
> var idStr = elt.id; // Get the id.
> elt.id = idStr; // Set the id
> ```

However, this is not going to fix your issues. You see, you guessed wrong when trying to use the getElementById function. This function looks at the page and finds the element with that id right now. If you don't have any element with the `characterSelected` id at first, then this variable you set is going to be `null` for the rest of time. Variables won't magically update when an element with that id is placed in the page.

And finally, you have missed the purpose of the [id attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) itself.

> Its purpose is to identify the element when linking (using a fragment
>   identifier), scripting, or styling (with CSS).

The purpose of an id is to identify an element uniquely. You might think: "that's what I'm doing". No. You're using an id to represent whether or not an element is selected. This is wrong. Depending on your objective, I would say: just store the selected element inside a variable. Then whenever you need to do something with the selected element, it's in that variable. If you need specific style for that element, then you could set a class to it. But the id isn't meant for this at all - in fact, an id isn't meant to change once an element is placed.